# Function to convert a string to character

Tags: oracle, postgresql, oracle11g, oracle10g

```
 select 'open' as "documentno" from c_order 
 union all
 select documentno as "documentno" from c_invoice
```

.This is not working in oracle.
i need a query that works in both oracle and postgres

Comment: "*a string to a character*" does not make sense. A string is composed of characters. `to_char('OPEN')` does not make much sense either. What are you trying to do? What is your underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: What datatype is `documentno`? And why are you selecting the same constant value for all rows in the `c_order` table? Again: what is the underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not provided enough information to answer your question.

My *guess* is that you want to include columns in a union that do not have the same data type and are looking for a way to cast a number to a character value (again I'm guessing because you didn't tell us what data type `documentno` is).

The following works in Oracle and Postgres:

```
select 'open' as "documentno" from c_order 
union all
select cast(documentno as varchar(20)) as "documentno" from c_invoice;
```

However: the first part of the union does not make sense. Why are your retrieving the same constant value for each and every row in `c_order` without any additional information from that table?